# XML Parsing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which consists of multiple records and I want to display all of them on one page. I have written some code but it's not helping me out.
Here some tags are optional so how I can I show "--" in that optional tag where it is not appearing?

### XML File

```
<doctors>
    <doctor specialization="Gynaecologist">
        <name>Alex Mashkin</name>
        <bachelor_degree>MBBS</bachelor_degree>
        <master_degree>Master in Gynaecology</master_degree>
        <experience>7 Years</experience>
        <available_timings>12PM to 5PM</available_timings>
        <fees>500</fees>
        <operation_charges>20000</operation_charges>
        <special_visit_charges>1000</special_visit_charges>
    </doctor>
    <doctor specialization="Sergeon">
        <name>Dazy Deepy</name>
        <bachelor_degree>MBBS</bachelor_degree>
        <master_degree>Master in Surgery</master_degree>
        <experience>10 Years</experience>
        <available_timings>11AM to 2PM</available_timings>
        <fees>900</fees>
        <operation_charges>25000</operation_charges>
        <special_visit_charges>1800</special_visit_charges>
    </doctor>
    <doctor specialization="Dentist">
        <name>Mona Bralia</name>
        <bachelor_degree>BDS</bachelor_degree>
        <experience>3 Years</experience>
        <available_timings>4PM to 8PM</available_timings>
        <fees>300</fees>
        <special_visit_charges> 600</special_visit_charges>
    </doctor> </doctors>
```

### HTML Code

(snippet)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //Code for IE7,Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        //code for IE6,IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "XMLFile.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("doctor");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      { 
      document.write("<tr><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getAttribute("specialization"));
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("bachelor_degree")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("master_degree")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("experience")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("available_timings")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("fees")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("operation_charges")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
      document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("special_visit_charges")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td></tr>");
      }
    document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean, specifically? A total failure to run? Are there any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Actually It doesn't show the proper output. I want to show master degee to only some of the doctor and if it doesn't get for one it should give some "---" symbol that explain that doctor hasn't done the master degree...

Comment: It will make it easier for us to help you if you removed all the code that has nothing to do with your problem of displaying master's degrees or not, and it might in fact lead you to see the solution for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of research I have find out shortest way to iterate all the elements with attribute. 
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    //Code for IE7,Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    //code for IE6,IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "XMLFile.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
y=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i=0;i<y.length;i++)
{
    if (y[i].nodeType!=3)
    {
        //This code for printing attribute of a tag(you have to give attribute name).
        document.write("<br>" + y[i].getAttributeNode('specialization').nodeName + ":  ");
        document.write(y[i].getAttributeNode('specialization').nodeValue + "<br>");
        for (z=0;z<y[i].childNodes.length;z++)
        {
            if (y[i].childNodes[z].nodeType!=3)
            {
                            //This is for Node Name.
                document.write(y[i].childNodes[z].nodeName + ": ");
                            //This is for Node Value.
                document.write(y[i].childNodes[z].textContent + "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to iterate all `<doctor>` elements, and check the children of each. That means you can't just get all `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("master_degree")` from the document and think it's `i`th item would match the current doctor, as some doctors do not have a `<master_degree>` elemenent. Instead, check it for each of them by applying `getElementsByTagName` on the doctor itself, and count how many master degrees you have selected (might be none, might be more than one?).

```
// a mapping from HTML ids to XML tag names, to make it more programmatical
var map = {dname:"name", bdegree":"bachelor_degree", mdegree:"master_degree", exp:"experience", availibity:"available_timings, fee:"fees", opcharge:"operation_charges", spcharge:"special_visit_charges"};
// and from HTML ids to XML attribute names of the doctor
var attrmap = {spec:"specialisation"};

… // load XML etc - you should do it asynchronous, btw
var doctors = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("doctor"),
    doctorCount = doctors.length;
for (var i=0; i<doctorCount; i++) {
    var doc = doctors[i];
    for (var id in map) {
        var elements = doc.getElementsByTagName(map[id]),
            var result = "";
        if (!elements.length)
            result = "---";
        for (var j=0; j<elements.length; j++)
            if (elements[i].firstChild)
                result += elements[i].firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById(id).innerText += result;
    }
    for (var id in attrmap) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerText += doc.getAttribute(attrmap[id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried "if(document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("master_degree").length>0))" But I am getting something strange output. It is showing me true false instead of master degree.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, btw. And what's strange in your output? You write the boolean result of whether there are more than zero `master_degree` elements in your `x[i]`

Comment: I write if(document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("master_degree").length>0))
    {
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("master_degree")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); }  What's wrong here..??? And why not to write document.write? what's wrong in that?

Comment: Why write `x[i].getElementsByTagName("master_degree")` twice? Else it looks good to me, what error do you get?

Comment: Hey I tried ur code but it's not working at all... I dnt see any output.

Comment: It should be doing the same thing as your [previous code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13235804/3). I'm sure you can adapt it to your table-generation.